# CoreData save record without contextsave

Tags: core-data, swift3

Project is my NSManagedObject

```
 let proj = Project(context: context!)
 //at this point when i try to fetch for my proj nothing is there

 proj.title = "title"
 //at this point I can fetch my project record
```

now i try

```
let proj = Project(context: context!)
let proj1 = Project(context: context!)
//at this point when i try to fetch for my proj nothing is there

 proj.title =  "title"
 //I find 1 record
```

I change my code a bit

```
let proj = Project(context: context!)
let proj1 = Project(context: context!)
//when i try to fetch for my proj nothing is there

 proj.title = "title"
 proj1.title = "title"

 //I find 2 record
```

it seems like proj.title = "title" is saving the record

I do not have .save() inside my subclass

why is this ? I am confused

i thought object are only saved when you call 
managedObjectContext.save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object exists immediately after insert within the ManagedObjectContext.

The `.save()` pushes the changes from the MOC to its parent context, or to the persistent store. The idea is that you can manipulate the objects within a scratch MOC, but throw them away in response to a "Cancel".

If you do a fetch using a different MOC that's pointing to the same persistent store, you won't see the changes without a `.save()` on the MOC you're using for the insertions.